# Creating a file asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, file-io, async-await

How can I modify this method to call it asynchronously?

```
private void Write(string fileName, data)
{
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, data);           
}
```

Comment: `StreamWriter.WriteAsync` or `FileStream.WriteAsync`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155757.aspx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look into [`FileStream.WriteAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7db28s3c(v=vs.110).aspx) (Note you have to use the proper overload which takes a `bool` indicating if it should run async:)

```
public async Task WriteAsync(string data)
{
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"File", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 
        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, buffer.Length, true))
    {
         await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you want to use your `string data` and avoid the transformation to a `byte[]`, you can use the more abstracted and less verbose [`StreamWriter.WriteAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193364(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which accepts a string:

```
public async Task WriteAsync(string data)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"FileLocation"))
    {
         await sw.WriteAsync(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Prabhu Yes, he has to `await WriteAsync`

Comment: Where does it write the data (which is a string) here?

Comment: @Prabhu I edited my answer to make it clear. The `buffer` variable needs to be a `byte[]`, So we need to transform the string

Comment: awesome thanks...do you know if there is one for Append as well?

Comment: @Prabhu There is an overload of the [`StreamWriter` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a `bool` that represents if you want to append to an existing file.

Comment: minor performance optimization in the code you posed - there is no need to `async` and `await` here. you can `return  sw.WriteAsync(data);` directly

Comment: Strange my edition was rejected, but the Encoding should be UTF8 as like in original WriteAllText() method

Comment: Here only the write operation is async, but the file creation (changing a directory entry) is not. File and directory async creation is not supported in .NET, only because the WinAPI doesn't support callbacks for it, so one would always need to use a thread pool.

Comment: Making the `bufferSize` parameter `buffer.Length` seems like a mistake - the default buffer size is fine (4KB).

Answer (score 14):

With .NetCore 2.0 you can just use [File.WriteAllTextAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltextasync?view=netcore-2.0)